# How can I turn off error printing in libxml2.parseDoc?

Tags: python, xml, libxml2

When using the library, I expect an exception for bad input, but I do not want it to start printing things to stderr.  How can I configure it to not print anything?

Here's an example from the REPL of what I am talking about:

```
>>> import libxml2
>>> try:
...     libxml2.parseDoc('junk')
... except:
...     pass
... 
Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
junk
^
>>>
```

With that code I expect to see nothing printed out.  I found [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801315/disable-debug-output-in-libxml2-and-xmlsec) about a similar issue with the c++ xmllib2, but I don't see a way to do that with the python version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can **disable error logging** for `libxml2` by registering a silent error handler:

```
def noerr(ctx, str):
    pass

libxml2.registerErrorHandler(noerr, None)
```

Source: http://xmlsoft.org/python.html